# Why does Java function multiply the quantity when adding to cart?

Tags: java

I am trying to add a new product into cart. When I add the first product, it's added correctly. When the product already exist, it increment correctly but when there are products existing into cart and try to add a new product it adds 1 more in quantity.

```
protected void addToCart(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
    int productId = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("productId"));
    if (session.getAttribute("cart") == null) {
        ArrayList<Item> item = new ArrayList<>();
        item.add(new Item(ProductModel.getProduct(productId), 1));
        session.setAttribute("cart", item);
    } else {
        ArrayList<Item> item = (ArrayList<Item>) session.getAttribute("cart");
        for (int i = 0; i < item.size(); i++) {
            // This line increment the product correctly
            if (item.get(i).getProduct().getId() == productId) {
                item.get(i).setQuantity(item.get(i).getQuantity() + 1);
            } else {
                // Here the product is added twice instead of once
                item.add(new Item(ProductModel.getProduct(productId), 1));
            }
            session.setAttribute("cart", item);
        }
        
    }
}
```

What would be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the code adds a new item to the cart when you find an item that doesn't have the same product ID. What it should be doing is add a new item if *no item* has the same product ID.

You can use a boolean variable to keep track of whether you found an item with a matching product ID or not, and add a new item in the loop if you did not.

```
boolean foundExistingProduct = false;
ArrayList<Item> item = (ArrayList<Item>) session.getAttribute("cart");
for (int i = 0; i < item.size(); i++) {
    if (item.get(i).getProduct().getId() == productId) {
        item.get(i).setQuantity(item.get(i).getQuantity() + 1);
        session.setAttribute("success", "An existing product is added to shopping cart!");
        request.getRequestDispatcher("Products").forward(request, response);
        foundExistingProduct = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (!foundExistingProduct) {
    item.add(new Item(ProductModel.getProduct(productId), 1));
    session.setAttribute("success", "Another product is added to shopping cart!");
    request.getRequestDispatcher("Products").forward(request, response);
}

session.setAttribute("cart", item);
```